# Idiomatic way of branching json parsing in kotlin

Tags: json, jackson, kotlin

Let's say that we have a `JsonNode` object `jsonNodeObj` that needs to be parsed to one of multiple classes `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC`, etc. I could do the following (couldn't be more ugly):

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper()
try {
  mapper.treeToValue(jsonNodeObj, ClassA::class.java)
} catch (e1: Exception) {
  try {
    mapper.treeToValue(jsonNodeObj, ClassB::class.java)
  } catch (e2: Exception) {
    try {
      mapper.treeToValue(jsonNodeObj, ClassC::class.java)
    } catch (e3: Exception) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way like using `when` somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely a better way to do this. You can define a function that returns true on success and false on exception like so:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> ObjectMapper.treeToValueOrNull<T>(node : TreeNode) : T?
    = try { treeToValue(node, T::class.java) }
    catch (ex : Exception) { null }
```

This works because in Kotlin `try`-`catch`-statements can have a return value. Now, you can use `when` to process the json:

```
lateinit var object : Any
when {
    mapper.treeToValueOrNull<ClassA>(jsonNodeObj)?.let { object = it } != null
        -> dosthA(object as ClassA)
    mapper.treeToValueOrNull<ClassB>(jsonNodeObj)?.let { object = it } != null
        -> dosthB(object as ClassB)
    mapper.treeToValueOrNull<ClassC>(jsonNodeObj)?.let { object = it } != null
        -> dosthC(object as ClassC)
}
```

[pdvrieze found an even shorter solution](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/idiomatic-way-of-branching-json-parsing-in-kotlin/6185/2):

```
val object = mapper.treeToValueOrNull<ClassA>(jsonNodeObj)
          ?: mapper.treeToValueOrNull<ClassB>(jsonNodeObj)
          ?: mapper.treeToValueOrNull<ClassC>(jsonNodeObj)
```

Comment: Intellij complained about `<T>`: Only one type parameter list is allowed for a function.

Comment: Also, What I want to do is actually return the parsed object. I cannot figure out a way to return the parsed object without running it twice like `when { mapper.treeToValue<ClassA>(jsonNodeObj) -> mapper.treeToValue<ClassA>(jsonNodeObj) ...`, which looks weird.

Comment: I tried to update the answer with @{Paul de Vrieze}'s better solution but got rejected. Here's the link to it: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/idiomatic-way-of-branching-json-parsing-in-kotlin/6185/2

Comment: Yep the idea of stack overflow is not to have one perfect solution but the possibility of multiple answers of which the OP (you) can mark the solution that worked for him and everybody can vote for good answers

Comment: @breezymri feel free to add a second answer but dont edit mine

Comment: I guess my wording was not 100% accurate. I wanted to say that Paul de Vrieze had an improved version based on your answer. And that's why I wanted to edit your answer such that I can still keep it accepted but reflect the optimal solution that I eventually went with.

Comment: Ok I looked at it an it seems to be pritty similar to my answer. I'll edit it accordingly